# Custom directive gets error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**app.js**

```
angular.module('symphony', ['symphony.directives'])
```

---

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('symphony.directives')

.directive('breadCrums', ['', function(){
    return {
         restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
         templateUrl: '/angular/includes/breadcrums.html',
         replace: true,

    };
}]);
```

It says : `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- breadCrumsDirective`

Why this error coming? My other controllers are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with loading of `'symphony.directives'` module.

- Missed empty braces as 2nd module parameter
- remove injector (if you don't use it)

Change it to:

```
angular.module('symphony.directives', []).
directive('breadCrums', function(){
return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: '/angular/includes/breadcrums.html',
     replace: true
   };
});
```

Fixed template <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fess81/9Ymvt/2058/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Now coming Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: @Namal I think we answered on your question and this way should work. About other issues, please open new question

Comment: No it's my falut. Thanks @Max.

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue with your directive definition. You ask angular to inject a service which name is an empty string. Angular's injector reports that this service does not exist because it can not find its provider.

Your code should work with this simple fix:

```
.directive('breadCrums', function(){
    return {
         restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
         templateUrl: '/angular/includes/breadcrums.html',
         replace: true,

    };
});
```